# Почему поле ConfInforms в users пусто?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class ContactContext : DbContext
    {
        public ContactContext()
            : base("MyBases")
        { }
        // Это свойство ссылается на таблицу в базе данных
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContactInformation> ContInform { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInformation>().HasRequired(p => p.Contact)
                .WithMany(b => b.ContInforms)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ContactId);
            modelBuilder.Ignore<ContactInformation>();
        }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ContactInformation> ContInforms { get; set; }

        public Contact()
        {
            ContInforms = new List<ContactInformation>();
        }

    }
    public class ContactInformation
    {
        public int? ContactId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Skype { get; set; }
        public string Another { get; set; }

        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (ContactContext db = new ContactContext())
            {
                db.Contacts.Load();
                Contact Contact1 = new Contact
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Вася1",
                    SurName = "Пупкин1",
                    MiddleName = "Николаевич1",
                    BirthDate = "1.11.1990",
                    Organization = "Купол1",
                    Position = "programmer1",
                };
                Contact Contact2 = new Contact
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Вася2",
                    SurName = "Пупкин2",
                    MiddleName = "Николаевич2",
                    BirthDate = "1.11.1990",
                    Organization = "Купол2",
                    Position = "programmer2",

                };
                // добавляем их в бд
                db.Contacts.Add(Contact1);
                db.Contacts.Add(Contact2);
                //Contact contact2 = db.Contacts
                //    .Where(o => o.Id == 1)
                //    .FirstOrDefault();
                //db.Contacts.Remove(contact2);
                db.SaveChanges();


                ContactInformation ContactInformation1 = new ContactInformation
                {
                    Another = "1",
                    ContactId = 0,
                    Email = "1",
                    Id = 0,
                    Phone = "1",
                    Skype = "1",
                    Contact = Contact1
                };
                ContactInformation ContactInformation2 = new ContactInformation
                {
                    Another = "2",
                    ContactId = 0,
                    Email = "2",
                    Id = 0,
                    Phone = "2",
                    Skype = "2",
                    Contact = Contact1

                };
                ContactInformation ContactInformation3 = new ContactInformation
                {
                    Another = "3",
                    //ContactId = 0,
                    Email = "3",
                    //Id = 0,
                    Phone = "3",
                    Skype = "3",
                    Contact = Contact2
                };
                try
                {
                    db.ContInform.AddRange(new List<ContactInformation> { ContactInformation1, ContactInformation2, ContactInformation3 });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Объекты успешно сохранены");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                // получаем объекты из бд и выводим на консоль
                var users = db.Contacts;
                Console.WriteLine("Список объектов:");
                foreach (Contact c in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} - {2} - {3} - {4} - {5} - {6} - {7}", c.Id, c.Name, c.SurName, c.MiddleName, c.Organization, c.Position, c.BirthDate, c.ContInforms);
                }

            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Потому что для `EntityFramework` нужно, чтобы вы заполнили идентификатор `ContactId` правильно. Вы же пишете туда:

```
 ContactId = 0
```

Соответственно именно поэтому там и пусто.

После того, как Вы вызываете метод `db.SaveChanges();` у объектов `Contact1` и  `Contact2` присваиваются их идентификаторы. Иными словами, если Вы после вызова этого метода взглянете в режиме отладки на их идентификаторы, к примеру `Contact1.Id`, то увидите там не нулевой идентификатор. Достаточно будет заполнить только `ContactId`, без заполнения свойства `Contact` при создании `ContactInformation` и писать следующее:

```
ContactInformation ContactInformation1 = new ContactInformation
{
    Another = "1",
    ContactId = Contact1.Id,
    Email = "1",
    Id = 0,
    Phone = "1",
    Skype = "1"
};
```

И тогда Вы будете там видеть не нулевое поле.

Либо, Вы можете присвоить поле, содержащее объект класса, при этом не присваивая идентификатора в виде внешнего ключа - и тогда тоже получите необходимую связь и значение, пример:

```
ContactInformation ContactInformation1 = new ContactInformation
{
    Another = "1",
    Contact = Contact1,
    Email = "1",
    Id = 0,
    Phone = "1",
    Skype = "1"
};
```

Также `EntityFramework` достаточно умен, чтобы разбирать и понимать вложенные конструкции. К примеру, если Вы напишете вот так:

```
ContactInformation ContactInformation1 = new ContactInformation
{
    Another = "1",
    Contact = new Contact
        {
            Name = "Вася",
            SurName = "Пупкин",
            MiddleName = "Николаевич",
            BirthDate = "1.11.1990",
            Organization = "Купол",
            Position = "director",
        },
    Email = "1",
    Id = 0,
    Phone = "1",
    Skype = "1"
};
```

И после этого вызовете метод сохранения изменений: `db.SaveChanges();` - объекты должны будут добавлены в базу и связь между ними будет создана автоматически.

Comment: Не надо вот так делать: `ContactId = Contact1.Id`, в данном случае достаточно `Contact = Contact1`!

Comment: @PavelMayorov,  я с Вами не согласен. Присвоить значение свойству, где хранится идентификатор - более чем достаточно и менее ресурсозатратно.